# proper usage of value-of select to select required value in data Entry field

Tags: xslt

I've been struggling to get the output I want using the xsl:value-of select, however I seem not to be on the right track with this.

This is the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ENTRY NAME="CustomerSite" CLASS="Site">
  <ENTRY NAME="Production" CLASS="Configuration Set">
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="VersionMinor">
  <VALUE>0</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="VersionMajor">
  <VALUE>3</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="Site Identifier">
  <VALUE>1</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="VersionPoint">
  <VALUE>0</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="Note ID Dial String Digits">
  <VALUE>*90</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
<ENTRY NAME="Account Codes" CLASS="Account Codes">
<ATTRIBUTE NAME="Enable">
  <VALUE>No</VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE>
  </ENTRY>
</ENTRY>
```

And this is the XLS code I use:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="ENTRY">
          <xsl:if test="@CLASS='SITE'">
            <xsl:value-of select="./ENTRY/@NAME"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The data I want to extract is the 'CustomerSite' used as the NAME value in the first Entry field.

Thanks
Niteowls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem here is, that the value of attribute CLASS is "Site" (not "SITE").

But than your output will be "Production" because the for-each select the first (root) ENTRY and than the value of select the child ENTRY NAME attribute.

To get "CustomerSite" use.

```
<xsl:if test="@CLASS='Site'">
    <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Or much better (no for-each needed):

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ENTRY[@CLASS='Site']/@NAME"/>
```

Comment: I'm afraid i've been looking at this rather too long and overlooked the capitalization of the Site test :( thanks for pointing that out.